# Play/Scala: Making unknown number of I/O calls in parallell, watining for the results

Tags: scala, concurrency, playframework-2.0

So, I read the article [here](http://engineering.linkedin.com/play/play-framework-async-io-without-thread-pool-and-callback-hell) about parallel comprehension. He gives the following code example:

```
// Make 3 parallel async calls
val fooFuture = WS.url("http://foo.com").get()
val barFuture = WS.url("http://bar.com").get()
val bazFuture = WS.url("http://baz.com").get()

for {
  foo <- fooFuture
  bar <- barFuture
  baz <- bazFuture
} yield {
  // Build a Result using foo, bar, and baz
  Ok(...)
}
```

All fine so far, but, I am in a situation where I don't know how many WS.get()'s I need to do always, I want it to be dynamic. So for instance:

```
val checks = Seq(callOne(param), callTwo(param))
```

Where the calls are:

```
def callOne(param: String): Future[Boolean] = {
  // do something and return the Future with a true/false value
  Future(true)
}

def callTwo(param: String): Future[Boolean] = {
  // do something and return the Future with a true/false value
  Future(false)
}
```

So, my question is, how shall I react on the results of my sequence with WS calls (or database queries for that matter), in a for-yield?

I have given two example of calls, but I want the same code be able to process 1 to many number of calls in parallel and gather the results in the for-yield to ultimately proceed to do other things.

Important: All calls should be carried out in parallel, the quickest ones will complete before the slow ones without any respect to what order they are fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Future.sequence](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$@sequence[A,M[X]%3C:TraversableOnce[X]](in:M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]])(implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]],A,M[A]],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[M[A]]) is likely what you want.

Example usage:

```
val futures = List(WS.url("http://foo.com").get(), WS.url("http://bar.com").get())
Future.sequence(futures) # => Transforms a Seq[Future[_]] to Future[Seq[_]]
```

The future returns from Future.sequence will not be completed until the all of the futures in the input sequence are completed.

**Bonus:**

If your futures are heterogeneously typed, and you need to preserve that type, you can use Hlist. I've written the following snippet which will take an Hlist of futures, and transform it to a Future containing an Hlist of resolved values:

```
import shapeless._
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext,Future}

object FutureHelpers {
  object FutureReducer extends Poly2 {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    implicit def f[A, B <: HList] = at[Future[A], Future[B]] { (f, resultFuture) =>
      for {
        result <- resultFuture
        value <- f
      } yield value :: result
    }
  }

  // Like Future.sequence, but for HList
  // hsequence(Future { 1 } :: Future { "string" } :: HNil)
  // => Future { 1 :: "string" :: HNil }
  def hsequence[T <: HList](hlist: T)(implicit
    executor: ExecutionContext,
    folder: RightFolder[T, Future[HNil], FutureReducer.type]) = {
    hlist.foldRight(Future.successful[HNil](HNil))(FutureReducer)
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's what I'm looking for, but, how do I populate that `futures` dynamically before I wait for all to finish?

Comment: If you have a urls: Seq[String|, urls map (WS.url).

Comment: Ok so I tested Future.sequence around a bit but they are being carried out in order, 1, 2, 3 ... etc, I'm really looking for a solution to fire everything at once and just waiting for all of them to end.

Comment: What you are looking for is exactly what Future.sequence does.

Comment: In other words, your Futures will be scheduled as soon as you instantiate them. So, if you instantiate a list of Futures, they will be scheduled concurrently (as much as your ExecutionContext permits; you may need to tune your executor depending on your device to get higher parallelism as it defaults to 2 times # of cores on machine).

Future.sequence will just wait for every future in the list, and then provide you with a list of results (in the same order as the provided list of futures).

Comment: After using your suggestions and some debugging, it is now working exactly as I wanted it to. Learned a few bits on the way. Thank you.